# Best method for dealloaction in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

In Cocos2dx, which is the best method for deallocation?

1. Override @"release()" method of ccObject.
2. Create a Distructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macro already defined in cocos2d-x.

```
#define CC_SYNTHESIZE_RETAIN(varType, varName, funName)    \
private: varType varName; \
public: virtual varType get##funName(void) const { return varName; } \
public: virtual void set##funName(varType var)   \
{ \
    if (varName != var) \
    { \
        CC_SAFE_RETAIN(var); \
        CC_SAFE_RELEASE(varName); \
        varName = var; \
    } \
}

#define CC_SAFE_DELETE(p)            do { if(p) { delete (p); (p) = 0; } } while(0)
#define CC_SAFE_RELEASE(p)            do { if(p) { (p)->release(); } } while(0)
#define CC_SAFE_RETAIN(p)            do { if(p) { (p)->retain(); } } while(0)
```

For example:

```
CC_SYNTHESIZE_RETAIN(CCLayer*, m_layer, Layer);
```

Then you can assign `m_layer` with `setLayer(new_layer);`, and get it with `getLayer()`.

And this macro only works for object extend `CCObject`.

Comment: can you please explain this in brief with some example or something , how we exactly use this in cocos2d-x.